# Does the MapInfo centroid function guarantee a centroid within the polygon?

Tags: mapinfo, os-mastermap

I wish to calculate the centroids of a large number of building polygons in OS MasterMap using MapInfo.  MapInfo calculates the centroid using the object's Minimum Bounding Rectangle.  Theoretically could a building's shape mean the centroid was outwith the building's footprint?

Answer (score 2):

According to this post the centroid is initially forced to be inside of the polygon.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mapinfo-l/cb5x5g-50mo